# style an html checkbox with own styled images

Tags: html, css

Can anyone tell me please how do i change default style for:

```
<input type=checkbox...>
```

so it will use my 2 styled pictures instead of default style??

tnx!!

Comment: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-checkbox-radio/

Comment: This question is asked a lot on stackoverflow. Did you not search stackoverflow before asking the question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You can replace default radio/checkbox by removing the default style first, then apply pseudo element as shown in the snippet.

**PS:** For this, Use font-awesome library

```css
.checkbox-custom, .radio-custom {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;   
}

.checkbox-custom, .checkbox-custom-label, .radio-custom, .radio-custom-label {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox-custom-label, .radio-custom-label {
    position: relative;
}

.checkbox-custom + .checkbox-custom-label:before, .radio-custom + .radio-custom-label:before {
    content: '';
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.checkbox-custom:checked + .checkbox-custom-label:before {
    content: "\f00c";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    background: rebeccapurple;
    color: #fff;
}

.radio-custom + .radio-custom-label:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.radio-custom:checked + .radio-custom-label:before {
    content: "\f00c";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    color: #bbb;
}

.checkbox-custom:focus + .checkbox-custom-label, .radio-custom:focus + .radio-custom-label {
  outline: 1px solid #ddd; /* focus style */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
HTML  CSS   Result
Edit on 
    <form>
        <h2>CSS Radio Buttons and checkboxes: Border</h2>
        <h5>Checkboxes and radio buttons with a border checked state: Pure CSS</h5>
        <p><em>Uses an inset box shadow for the bordered effect on the checked state.</em></p>
        <br>
        <h2>Radio Buttons</h2>
        <div>
            <input id="radio-1" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group" type="radio" checked>
            <label for="radio-1" class="radio-custom-label">First Choice</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input id="radio-2" class="radio-custom"name="radio-group" type="radio">
            <label for="radio-2" class="radio-custom-label">Second Choice</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input id="radio-3" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group" type="radio">
            <label for="radio-3" class="radio-custom-label">Third Choice</label>
        </div>

      <h2>Checkboxes</h2>
      <div>
        <input id="checkbox-1" class="checkbox-custom" name="checkbox-1" type="checkbox" checked>
        <label for="checkbox-1" class="checkbox-custom-label">First Choice</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="checkbox-2" class="checkbox-custom" name="checkbox-2" type="checkbox">
        <label for="checkbox-2" class="checkbox-custom-label">Second Choice</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="checkbox-3" class="checkbox-custom" name="checkbox-3" type="checkbox">
        <label for="checkbox-3"class="checkbox-custom-label">Third Choice</label>    
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use css changing the element next to the `checkbox`.
In this example it's the background color. Just replace it with your images.

For example: https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
   visibility: hidden;
   /* For mobile, it's typically better to position checkbox on top of clickable
      area and turn opacity to 0 instead. */
}

/* Default State */
label {
   background: green;
   width: 400px;
   height: 100px;
   line-height: 100px;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}

/* Toggled State */
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label {
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
<label for="toggle-1">Do Something</label>
```